# Bootstrap Table only displays when user is logged in

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-table

I am using [Bootstrap Table extension](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/) on one of my WordPress CMS pages. When I am logged into WordPress backend and visit the page the table shows up just fine. However, if I log out and visit the same page only table headers show up but they are no longer styled and no data is displayed. Below is my implementation:

**Code within the page with JSON file url included to grab the data:**

```
<table data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-toggle="table" data-url="https://example.com/assets/maps/data/out/file.json">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="first_name">First Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="last_name">Last Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="org_name">Organization</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="state">State</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="country">Country</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="cert_type">Certification Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Here is what is added to the header file to include the extension files:**

```
<?php if ($post->ID == 1174) { ?>                   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/assets/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

I made sure that there that jQuery and etc has no conflicts and is only loaded once. I am really not sure what the issue is. I am also not seeing any issue in the console.

Comment: Example.com in bootstrap table assets (CSS and Js) is only a misprint?

Comment: @beaver I replaced my domain name with example.com. Code executes just fine with great results but for some reason only when I am logged into the WP Admin.

Comment: Data-url is accessible both to logged and guest visitors? Have you checked the network tab in web developer tools (Chrome)?

Comment: Yes. It s a small json file that is on the same server. I can access the json file without being logged in just fine and from any computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional troubleshooting in WordPress I came to the conclusion that the X Theme and its Cornerstone editor were the issue. To solve the issue I took the table HTML out of the page and converted it into a function in the functions.php file. Below are the details:

**Moving the table code to functions.php as a function**

```
function c_table() {
    return '<table data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-toggle="table" data-url="https://example.com/assets/maps/data/out/file.json">'
            .'<thead>'
                .'<tr>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="first_name">First Name</th>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="last_name">Last Name</th>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="org_name">Organization</th>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="state">State</th>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="country">Country</th>'
                    .'<th data-sortable="true" data-field="cert_type">Certification Type</th>'
                .'</tr>'
            .'</thead>'
        .'</table>';
    }
add_shortcode('custom_script_c_table', 'c_table');
```

**Using the shortcode**

Once the function has been created I updated my page with the following shortcode:

```
[custom_script_c_table]
```

Answer (score -1):

Save a subset of your data at MYJSON.com  - this simulates a link you know works. 
 Replace your url for the json with a link from myjson.com.  You can also check the url ("https://example.com/assets/maps/data/out/file.json") directly in your browswer without running your page.  This will isolate a data problem from a possible permissions problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, JSON is fine and everything was working but not in when I logged out of the WP admin panel.